# Can't authenticate to local MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I recently started working on a project with Express and since I'm using Node.js as backend I chose MongoDB as my database. It's my first time working with Mongo but I can't authenticate with Express, it works fine from terminal. I followed the guide from MogoDB blog [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database). I tried using their Atlas service where I had no problem authenticating. I'm using [MongoDB driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). Here's how my connection URI looks like:

```
const uri = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@127.0.0.1/cloud?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```

I tried changing mongodb:// to mongodb+srv:// but that resulted in invalid connection string error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the [authentication database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource), usually `admin`:

```
const uri = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@127.0.0.1/cloud?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```

If you don't specify it then in your case MonogDB defaults the authentication database to `cloud` - which is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing mongodb on the web you can click on connect and on connect your application. You will show the uri to copy paste starting with

*mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@CLUSTER/DATABASE*

You forgot to specify the CLUSTER. Currently is your local Database

Comment: It's in the title, I'm trying to authenticate to my local database.

Comment: Try to connect to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 ?